# How to use env in index.html within a react vite application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables, vite

I'm trying to access an env variable from my index.html file.

The code below seems to work in CRA but doesnt work with my vite, react project setup

`const APP_ID = '%REACT_APP_ID%'`

```
    <script>
      //Set your APP_ID
      const APP_ID = '%REACT_APP_ID%'

     ....

    </script>
```

my vite config file

```
import { defineConfig, splitVendorChunkPlugin } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import EnvironmentPlugin from 'vite-plugin-environment'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    splitVendorChunkPlugin(),
    react(),
    EnvironmentPlugin('all', { prefix: 'REACT_APP_' }),
  ],
})
```

Comment: `import.meta.REACT_APP_ID`?

Comment: I'm getting SyntaxError: Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module

Comment: I'm trying to use it within the index.html file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Replacing environment variables](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#html-env-replacement) in HTML files is supported since [Vite 4.2.0](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/blob/main/packages/vite/CHANGELOG.md#420-2023-03-16).

Define environment variables with the `VITE_` prefix, and wrap it between `%` in the HTML file.

For example:

```
<div>%VITE_SOME_KEY%</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixes my error but I guess I can't use it with the 

`import EnvironmentPlugin from 'vite-plugin-environment'`

Comment: I was using that plugin to make jest tests work with envs, is there a solution for that. when I use `import.meta.env`. All my jest unit tests fail

Answer (score 1):

You should to use only "%YOUR_VAR%" like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    const flag = "%VITE_TRACKING_ID%" 
          if (flag) {
            ...
</script>
```

have in mind you would need to update your Vite 4.2.0 as commented @Unmitigated

this is the thread to fix https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/3105#issuecomment-1441947641

Answer (score 0):

In `VITE` project you should import env from `import.meta.VITE_API_KEY`

**Remember!** : While use VITE project your all `env variables` names are starting with `VITE`

for example:

`VITE_API_KEY =randomKey ✅`

`API_KEY = randomKey ❌`

Comment: Thanks but doing this still doesnt allow me use envs within the index.html file

Comment: index.html is not a programming language and you can't use it. env is not use in .js/ts/jsx/tsx files

Comment: I'm trying to use it within the script tag of my index.html file in a vite react project

Comment: Create React App is able to do this "%ENV_VAR%"